# Notation for "congruent to a member of"

Tags: notation, modular-arithmetic

Is it acceptable to write $x\in S\pmod m$ to denote "$x$ is congruent to a member of $S$ modulo $m$"? Are there any established alternatives to this notation?

An example of use: "When $m\ge 5$ is prime, solutions exist for all $p\notin \{0,\pm 1\} \pmod m$".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version below seems clear and standard:

> When $m\ge 5$ is prime, solutions exist for all $p\not\equiv 0,\pm 1 \pmod m$

Also without negation:

> When $m\ge 5$ is prime, solutions exist for all $p\equiv 0,\pm 1 \pmod m$